# Get Request in Golang

Tags: http, go

this is a textbook example I try to put in use.

I get "BAD" as a result, it means that resp is nil, though I don't know how to fix it.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {

    resp, _ := http.Get("http://example.com/")

    if resp != nil {
        body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

        fmt.Println(string(body))

        resp.Body.Close()
    } else {
        fmt.Println("BAD")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to check your Internet settings first, as I cannot reproduce the problem.

Also, error handling in Go is crucial, so change your code to the one below and see if you get any error when making the request.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {

    resp, err := http.Get("http://example.com/")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    if resp != nil {
        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }

        fmt.Println(string(body))

        resp.Body.Close()
    } else {
        fmt.Println("BAD")
    }
}
```